# Как дополнить скомпилированный код в .dll посредством C++ vs

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Каким образом можно дополнить скомпилированный код внутри динамических библиотек .dll, в C++ ?
Мой исходный код выглядит таким образом:

```
FArchive& operator<<( FArchive& Ar, FPackageFileSummary& Sum )
{
guard(FfileSummary<<);
    Ar << Sum.Tag;
    Ar << Sum.FileVersion;
    Ar << Sum.PackageFlags;
return Ar;
unguard;
}
```

Как можно узнать адрес для подключения к этому коду/функции (Когда код уже в скомпилированном виде .dll)?

Если к примеру у меня есть адрес и подключусь к функции таким образом

```
GetProcAddress(LoadLibraryA("my.dll"), "?FArchive@@000");
```

Подразумевает ли такой доступ возможность добавления, к примеру, своих If else условий - внутри тела кода, то есть вместо

```
    Ar << Sum.Tag;
    Ar << Sum.FileVersion;
    Ar << Sum.PackageFlags;
```

стало

```
    if(x.version > 10)
  {
    Ar << Sum.Tag;
    Ar << Sum.FileVersion;
    Ar << Sum.PackageFlags;
  }
```

То есть если дополнить скомпилированный код в `my.dll`, посредством  моей библиотеки, которая подключается к приложению `my.exe`, будет ли оно таким образом переделывать код основной библиотеки `my.dll` которая так же подключена к `my.exe`?

Если это возможно - то как это сделать в коде? Есть какие нибудь толковые темы по этому поводу? Буду очень благодарен если мне укажут на то как это осуществить!

Comment: Вы хотите на лету изменить исполнимый код библиотеки? В таком варианте это невыполнимо без очень уж грубых хаков. Расскажите лучше о своей реальной задаче, есть шанс, что вам надо что-то попроще.

Comment: @Vlad Я думаю что это не нужно на лету, достаточно просто чтобы новая библиотека(моя)с кодом который изменяет скомпилированную библиотеку просто это делала, конечно же обе подключаются к одному и тому же приложению.

Comment: Ну, хм, что значит «изменяла скомпилированную библиотеку»? Нет, такое невозможно. Но с хорошей долей вероятности это вам и не надо. Расскажите вашу реальную задачу.

Comment: @Vlad - Я же ведь описал в самой теме, в my.dll описан FArchive& operator, внутри него есть `    Ar << Sum.Tag;
    Ar << Sum.FileVersion;
    Ar << Sum.PackageFlags;` я хочу это обернуть в if()else() По средством другой Библиотеки, поскольку полного доступа к исходникам my.dll у меня нету

Comment: Тогда вы можете, по идее, подставить вместо другой библиотеки свою, а из своей вызывать функции другой библиотеки. Но это не будет на деле изменение скомпилированной библиотеки.

Comment: @VladD ну это мне не надо

Comment: @LighFusion, если Вам достаточно менять код в начале функций, то может проще всего "попатчить" dll на диске? Т.е. Вы добавляете функцию с подходящим прологом и проверкой, а затем меняете в таблице адресов dll адрес проверяемой функции на адрес вашей, а в ней, если надо выполнять проверяемую, то прописываете jump на адрес в коде проверяемой после ее пролога (конечно, эту точку надо правильно добавить в таблицу символов dll). Мне кажется так проще всего разобраться со стеком и всеми возможными возвратами.

Comment: @avp Это конечно хороший вариант, но только если это можно проделать "На лету" т.е не редактируя искомую библиотеку, а делая это в памяти через другую библиотеку - которая связана с основной и с тем приложением для которой используется ? Если таким образом это можно сделать - не могли бы вы подробнее описать этот процесс конкретно для моего случая ? либо скинуть ссылку с примерами кода ?

Comment: Не понимаю, зачем это делать обязательно "на лету"? А конкретно помочь -- нет 1) я не пишу в винде. 2) в любом случае подобная работа потребует довольно много времени для экспериментов.

Comment: Если интересно -- еще одна идея. Ищете decompiler (и экспериментируете с ним), декомпилируете Core.dll, меняете исходник и собираете ее снова.

Comment: @avp =) К сожалению пересобрать Core.dll невозможно ! и помоему не нужно. Я не прошу писать код, мне достаточно будет - ссылку на толковую тему где это все подробно объясняется в коде. И на сколько я понял "на лету" Это подразумевает  создание Хука, и он выглядит подобным образом http://pastebin.com/pjhmUJAR http://pastebin.com/mAxm94vg ? Но я очень мало понимаю в его структуре, по этому хотелось бы просто найти тему которая описывает примерно все эту работу

Comment: Сами подумайте, ну откуда же я возьму ссылку, если я плотно этой темой не занимаюсь? / А пересобрать невозможно, это поскольку Вы априори не доверяете декомпилятору? Может это и правильные сомнения.

Comment: @avp нет не по этому, а потому что там слишком сложная структура - игровая, это ядро игры - его нельзя пересобирать.

Comment: Даже с целью изучения и тестирования? А вообще нас тут уже отправляют в чат (наверное C++\C ?)

Comment: Что поделать.!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решение нашлось в одном из уроков , который я нашел в [гугле](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RwH0ThOrodg)

Не хочу расписывать весь код что там указан ибо это бессмысленно - кому надо поймет !